# Register Taxonomy for multiple post types

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-post-type

I need to register taxonomies for 2 different post types, and I have tried to achieve this using the following code:

function add_custom_taxonomies() {

```
        // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
          $labels_adp = array(
            'name'                => _x( 'Apples', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'       => _x( 'Apple', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'        => __( 'Search Apples' ),
            'all_items'           => __( 'All Apples' ),
            'parent_item'         => __( 'Parent Apples' ),
            'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Apples:' ),
            'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Apples' ), 
            'update_item'         => __( 'Update Apples' ),
            'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Apples' ),
            'new_item_name'       => __( 'New Genre Apples' ),
            'menu_name'           => __( 'Apples' )
          );    

          $args_adp = array(
            'hierarchical'        => true,
            'labels'              => $labels_adp,
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_admin_column'   => true,
            'query_var'           => true,
            'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'apple' )
          );
          $labels_cw = array(
            'name'                => _x( 'Genres', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'       => _x( 'Genre', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'        => __( 'Search Genres' ),
            'all_items'           => __( 'All Genres' ),
            'parent_item'         => __( 'Parent Genre' ),
            'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Genre:' ),
            'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Genre' ), 
            'update_item'         => __( 'Update Genre' ),
            'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Genre' ),
            'new_item_name'       => __( 'New Genre Name' ),
            'menu_name'           => __( 'Genre' )
          );    

          $args_cw = array(
            'hierarchical'        => true,
            'labels'              => $labels_cw,
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_admin_column'   => true,
            'query_var'           => true,
            'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'genre' )
          );

          register_taxonomy( 'apple', array( 'adp' ), $args_adp );
          register_taxonomy( 'genre', array( 'cw' ), $args_cw );

    }
    add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_taxonomies', 0 );
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work at all, only rendering out one taxonomy one one of the post types. Don't know why.

Comment: "It doesn't work at all" is not helpful at all. What doesn't work? Why both taxonomies have the same labels and slugs? As @anstrangel0ver shows bellow, it's only a matter of using an `array` as... `array`.

Comment: @brasofilo the problem is that Only one taxonomy kicks into action. Not both.

Comment: I've tried your exact code and used `register_taxonomy( 'genresForAdp', array( 'post','portfolio' ), $args_adp ); register_taxonomy( 'genre', array( 'post','portfolio' ), $args_cw );` ---> **Both show up in the menus of Posts and Portfolios**, with the same names (why did you duplicate that???), but showing both nonetheless.

Comment: Try `add_action ('wp_loaded', ...);`

Comment: Nothing was working for me before...  I tried `init` and `plugins_loaded` but no luck, until I tried `wp_loaded` then it just worked.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an array right after the name of the taxonomy is defined:

```
register_taxonomy(
  'movie_name',
   array( 'reviews','news' ), 
  ..etc.. 
  )
```

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/one-taxonomy-for-multiple-post-types

Answer (score 0):

make two seperate function to register your post if you are trying to register individual taxonomy for different post type

```
function add_custom_taxonomies() {

            // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
             $labels_cw = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Genres', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Genre', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Genres' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Genres' ),
        'parent_item'         => __( 'Parent Genre' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Genre:' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Genre' ), 
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Genre' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Genre' ),
        'new_item_name'       => __( 'New Genre Name' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Genre' )
      );    

              $args_cw = array(
                'hierarchical'        => true,
                'labels'              => $labels_cw,
                'show_ui'             => true,
                'show_admin_column'   => true,
                'query_var'           => true,
                'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'genre' )
              );

                      register_taxonomy( 'genre', array( 'cw' ), $args_cw );


        }
        add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_taxonomies', 0 );
function add_custom_taxonomies1() {

            // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
               $labels_adp = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Apples', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Apple', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Apples' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Apples' ),
        'parent_item'         => __( 'Parent Apples' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Apples:' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Apples' ), 
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Apples' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Apples' ),
        'new_item_name'       => __( 'New Genre Apples' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Apples' )
      );    

              $args_adp = array(
                'hierarchical'        => true,
                'labels'              => $labels_adp,
                'show_ui'             => true,
                'show_admin_column'   => true,
                'query_var'           => true,
                'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'apple' )
              );

                      register_taxonomy( 'genre', array( 'adp' ), $args_adp );


        }
        add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_taxonomies1', 0 );
```

where in array( 'adp','cw' )  adp and cw are post type

Comment: I had considered this way, but the problem is that I don't want to apply the same 'genre' to both at all. They are separate for a reason. I've updated my code to be more clear about this.

Comment: check my answer i have edited .. if you want to register individual taxonomy for your post types make two functon for that